# Can One List Comprehension Be Used for both a Method and Class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple program that determines the lateral surface area and volume of a pyramid from preset values:

```
class RightSquarePyramid():
    def __init__(self, b=0, h=0):
        self.b = float(b)
        self.h = float(h)
        pass
    
    def slantHeight(self):
        self.l = sqrt((self.h ** 2 + (self.b / 2) ** 2))
        return self.l
    
    def lateralSurfaceArea(self):
        return 2 * self.b * self.l
    
    def volume(self):
        return 1/3 * self.b ** 2 * self.h

myList = [[2.5, 5.0], [4.3, 2.5], [8, 3]]

tri0, tri1, tri2 = [RightSquarePyramid(*x) for x in myList]
tri0.slantHeight()
tri1.slantHeight()
tri2.slantHeight()
print(round(tri0.lateralSurfaceArea(), 3), round(tri1.lateralSurfaceArea(), 3), round(tri2.lateralSurfaceArea(), 3))
print(round(tri0.volume(), 3), round(tri1.volume(), 3), round(tri2.volume(), 3))
```

This happens because we only have the height and length of the base, so we need to calculate the slant height first.

I am currently using this solution:

```
tri0, tri1, tri2 = [RightSquarePyramid(*x) for x in myList]
triForce = tri0, tri1, tri2
[x.slantHeight() for x in triForce]
# tri0.slantHeight()
# tri1.slantHeight()
# tri2.slantHeight()
print(round(tri0.lateralSurfaceArea(), 3), round(tri1.lateralSurfaceArea(), 3), round(tri2.lateralSurfaceArea(), 3))
print(round(tri0.volume(), 3), round(tri1.volume(), 3), round(tri2.volume(), 3))
```

But this essentially replaces 3 lines of code with 2.

Is there a way to use list comprehension for both `RightSquarePyramid()` and `slantHeight()`?
Maybe a common variable that I am just overlooking that could do it?

Comment: Have you considered using a for-loop?

Comment: A list comprehension that doesn't produce a list that is actually used is generally considered bad form.  *Why* do you need to make the calls to `.slantHeight()`?  If it initializes some attribute that your other methods rely on - then those other methods should really check for that condition, and call `.slantHeight()` themselves if needed.

Comment: What does `.slantHeight()` do? From its name I would expect it to return a value, but then you call it and ignore whatever value it might return. Please see [mcve].

Comment: Added class for clarification, it might be an issue with using a method in another method, and potentially combining the two into one method instead.

Comment: A suggestion that's not relevant to your question: put that code to calculate `self.l` straight in the `__init__`, and then you don't need to separately call `slantHeight` after creating the object.  (If you make it a `@dataclass(frozen=True)` you can make sure that `a` and `b` can't be changed after the object is created.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use loops in all the cases where you're currently enumerating all three `tri` variables.  There's no reason to destructure the list into those three variables in the first place.

The idiomatic way of writing a loop where you want to execute code for a side effect rather than doing something with its return value is to put it in a `for` loop rather than a list comprehension (the list comprehension is just going to give you a list of values that you don't want, probably `None`s).

For the `print` cases, you can use a generator expression and the `*` operator to pass the results of the iteration as arguments to the function.

```
triForce = [RightSquarePyramid(*x) for x in myList]
for t in triForce:
    t.slantHeight()

print(*(round(t.lateralSurfaceArea(), 3) for t in triForce))
print(*(round(t.volume(), 3) for t in triForce))
```

Since you're doing the exact same `print` routine with two different methods of the class, you could even put those in another loop:

```
for f in (
    RightSquarePyramid.lateralSurfaceArea,
    RightSquarePyramid.volume
):
    print(*(round(f(t), 3) for t in triForce)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Samwise and @Kaya3 for their inputs, I believe I solved the problem, here is the code below:

```
from math import sqrt


class RightSquarePyramid():
    def __init__(self, b=0, h=0):
        self.b = float(b)
        self.h = float(h)
        pass
    
    def slantHeight(self):
        return sqrt((self.h ** 2 + (self.b / 2) ** 2))
         
    
    def lateralSurfaceArea(self):
        self.l = self.slantHeight()
        return 2 * self.b * self.l
    
    def volume(self):
        return 1/3 * self.b ** 2 * self.h
    
myList = [[2.5, 5.0], [4.3, 2.5], [8, 3]]

triForce = [RightSquarePyramid(*x) for x in myList]
for f in (
    RightSquarePyramid.lateralSurfaceArea,
    RightSquarePyramid.volume
):
    print(*(round(f(t), 3) for t  in triForce))
```

Comment: I'd suggest removing `self.l` and just having `lateralSurfaceArea` do `return 2 * self.b * self.slantHeight()`.  If you don't have a `self.l` and just always calculate the slant height when it's needed, you never have to worry about whether `self.l` is up to date or not.

Comment: You can also remove the `pass` from your `__init__`; a `pass` is a placeholder in a completely empty block of code (which is why you might have seen it in an example), it doesn't actually do anything and there's no reason to have it in a block of code that's not otherwise empty.